# How do I print the data I read from the mbus meter in a meaningful way?

Tags: react-native, iot, metering

**Hello, I am developing an application in React Native. I have a hex format output from the Mbus meter and I want to show this data to the user on the screen in accordance with the Mbus protocol. But I can't just convert the incoming hex data into a string value.**

> I tried to find a library for this but I can't found it.